# Are Google Artifact Registry packages immutable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python-packaging, npm-package, google-artifact-registry

Are Python and NPM packages in Google artifact registry immutable.

That is, can we override a particular version?

Currently, I'm getting an error when trying to do so.

Is there any way to make it mutable so that the same version can be overwritten?